# create `class` for tkinter `Entry`

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a `class` for generic `Entry` instances.

I use `self.status` list in order to change it value ( part of automatic update ).

But, something very odd happens and I can't find it origin:

A functions is created named `status`, in order to change each `Entry` value. When the name of that function is changed to any other- i get this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    ####updated for entire traceback ####
File "schedualer.py", line 271, in <module>
sched_entries.get_stat[r-1][c].set(sch_file[r][c])
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Any ides why ?

Here's the class code.

```
class sched_entry (object):
  def __init__(self,master,r1,c1,offr,offc,bg1=["yellow"]):
    self.status=[]
    for r in range(r1):
        newrow=[]
        for c in range(c1):
            v=StringVar()
            z=Entry(master,relief=SUNKEN,width=cell_width,bg=bg1,textvariable=v,justify='center')
            z.grid(row=r+offr, column=c+offc)
            newrow.append(v)
        self.status.append(newrow)
  def status():           ###### when change to stat():   ---> I get the error
    return self.status
```

**I get the error when it is called:**

```
for r in range(1,tasks_total+1):   #update table with schdule.csv data
for c in range (len(sched_headers)-1):
    sched_entries.stat[r-1][c].set(sch_file[r][c]) ### error when method changed to "stat"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two things called `status`: a method and an instance variable containing a list. One will override the other; you need different names.

Although I'm not sure why you want the method in the first place, since it just returns the variable. You should remove that method altogether.

Comment: while names was same, it worked fine. When I did change `def status()` to `def stat()`- i got the described error

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work, not the code that does. But like I say, you don't need the method *at all*.

Comment: What does that mean? If you want help with code that doesn't work, show the code that doesn't work. Don't show different code that does work. Plus, always show the full traceback.

Comment: Well this is because you were never previously calling the method, you were referring to the instance variable which overwrote it. Now, you're referencing the method but still not calling it, because calling a method requires parentheses: `get_stat()`. However, for the third time, **you do not need this method and you should delete it**; refer to the `self.status` instance variable directly.

Comment: OK.... so when i tought I was calling `status`, I was actually got status from `self.status` ? hmmm

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are totally right, there where also a little details that produced errors to the OP. If you want check my answer. Anyway, the answer is perfect, is a plus one :)

Comment: I must add that both answers are corrent, @DanielRoseman's answer- that the method was not needed... 
much appreciate you answer - [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45073640/revisions]

Comment: @DamianLattenero's answer - how to call it right. THANK YOU BOTH !

I'll appreciate your help as weel in [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45073640/revisions]

Answer (score 2):

> Edit 2

**Important:** you forget to add the `self` parameter to the function defined in the class `sched_entry`.

The object in python that implement method `__getitem__()`, like dictionaries and lists, your problems comes when you say that:

```
self.status=[]
```

status is a list, so it has the `__getitem__()` but then you also say:

```
def status(self): 
    return self.status
```

and the problem occurs, you a method (in this case status), doesn't have the `__getitem__()`, so, you must rename one of those, you can do:

```
def get_status(self): #here goes the self parameter
    return self.status
```

> Edit

You also, most important, after see the edit, forget to add the `()`, that is how python actually executes a method, if you don't add it, you just get the reference of the method, but not the execution and the result of it (in your case, the list status)

```
sched_entries.get_status()[r-1][c].set(sch_file[r][c])
```

Comment: as answered to previous answer- when I change name ( as you also recommended ) **gives** that error.

Comment: @Guy.D, could you add the full code with modifications? and an example of when you init the objet sched_entry?

Comment: @Guy.D I understand now your error, you forget also to add the (), that is actually how python call a method and execute it

Comment: @Guy.D let me know if that works now, don't forget to vote and, if it was useful, accept it :)

Comment: @Guy.D, there is a diference if you write `sched_entries.get_status()` and `sched_entries.get_status`, the first will return self.status, the second will return the method get_status (without execute it, will return an object method)

Comment: to make sure that i don't have any indexing issues- i changed `sched_entries.get_stat()[0][0].set('guy')`

and got: `TypeError: get_stat() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: @Guy.D yes, forget to add the self parameter in the def, is def get_stat(self): ... Please, read the full updated answer, I hope that helps